# An algebra map between Hopf algebras that does not commute with the counit

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, bialgebras

Let $(H,\Delta,\epsilon,S)$ be a Hopf algebra. Can there exist an algebra map $\phi:H \to H$ such that
$$
\epsilon(\phi(g)) \neq \epsilon(g), ~~~~~ \textrm{ for some } g \in H?
$$
Does the anti-pode really have anything to do with this, or is it truly a question about bialgebras?

Comment: I am confused, the antipode $S$ does not even occur in your equation. In any case, as stated the answers seems to be "yes they exist" for trivial reasons. E.g. let $G$ be a finite group, $H=k^G$ the set of function $f:G\to k$. Then $\epsilon(f)=f(1)$. Now it is not hard to find examples for $G$ (and the resulting $H$) and $\phi$ that have $\epsilon(\phi(g))\neq\epsilon(g)$.

Answer (score 7):

Such a map can certainly exist. For instance, take the $k$-algebra $G = k \times k$, with
$$ \begin{aligned}
&\Delta(1,0) = (1,0) \otimes (1,0) + (0,1) \otimes (0,1), \\
&\Delta(0,1) = (1,0) \otimes (0,1) + (0,1) \otimes (1,0), \\
&S = \operatorname{id}, \\
&\epsilon(1,0) = 1, \\
&\epsilon(0,1) = 0.
\end{aligned} $$
(This is the Hopf algebra associated with the finite group of order $2$.)

Then the map $\phi \colon G \to G \colon (a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$ is an algebra morphism, but it does not preserve the counit.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this is isomorphic to the group Hopf algebra  of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @LorenzoDelVecchiopontopolos It's not isomorphic to the group Hopf algebra of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. It's the Hopf algebra of functions from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $k$. (This is the second example on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra#Examples.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But I thought that for prime order, all finite-dimensional Hopf algebras were isomorphic . . .

Comment: @LorenzoDelVecchiopontopolos That depends on the field. For instance, the specific example I gave is indeed isomorphic to the group algebra $k\mathbb{Z}_2$ if $\operatorname{char}(k) \neq 2$, but not if $\operatorname{char}(k) = 2$. In general, the group algebra $k\mathbb{Z}_n$ is isomorphic to the Hopf algebra of functions from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $k$ if and only if the polynomial $f(x) = x^n - 1$ has $n$ different roots in $k$ (in other words, if it splits over $k$ and has no multiple roots).

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be the Hopf algebra of functions on an algebraic group $G$. The map $\phi$ defines a map of algebraic varieties $\hat{\phi}:G\rightarrow G$. The counit condition you try to impose is equivalent to $\hat{\phi} (1_G)=1_G$. There is no reason for arbitrary $\hat{\phi}$ to take $1$ to $1$.